# Open Word document from command line with additional data source parameter

Tags: windows, command-line, ms-word, datasource, rundll32

It is possible to open a word document from the command line using this:

```
rundll32 url.dll,FileProtocolHandler path.to.word.document.doc
```

Unfortunately, that document needs an external data source, so the path of that data source has to be set manually once it is opened.

Is there a more convenient way to provide an additional parameter to point to the data source?

Answer (score 3):

You can open a word document using

```
winword.exe <filepath>
```

To use winword in command prompt you need to set your path variable like this

```
set path=%path%;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office14
```

Answer (score 2):

In the cmd instance I opened the document but just typing in the document name in

"whatever it's called.docx"

Answer (score 1):

If you use PowerShell, you can type "**ii FileName**".  For example, "**ii *.docx**" will open all the .docx files in the folder.  It works for all types of files, not just Word documents.